# Создать один запрос к двум бд

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, pdo

Как создать запрос к двум бд, у меня есть сервер и на нем имеются две бд, мне нужно будет сравнивать значение полей, допустим, из `db1.table1.column1 == db2.table1.column1`

Comment: ну вот прямо так и пишите select * from db1.t1 A join db2.t1 B where A.col1=B.col1. У пользователя который подключается к БД должны быть права на обе базы

Comment: $user = 'partsuser';
            $pass = 'pas';
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8', $user, $pass, array(
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
                )
            );
            $stmt = $dbh->query($sql); 
то есть всеравно что я тут выбрал базу db, я всеравно смогу обращаться к остальным?

Comment: @Mike Вам стоит оформить свой коментарий как ответ

Comment: все работает и вправду, я думал с PDO будет что то иначе, спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В большинстве СУБД поддерживающие отдельные базы данных (вы не указали в вопросе какая у вас) есть база по умолчанию, эта та которая указана в строке коннекта или позже явно выбрана (например `use db` для mysql). Таблицы выбранной БД доступны при прямом обращении.

Кроме того перед именем таблицы можно явно указать БД в которой эта таблица находится:

```
select *
  from db1.t1 A join db2.t1 B
    on A.col1=B.col1
```

Главное, что бы пользователь под которым вы подключаетесь имел права на таблицы обоих баз.

Answer (score 0):

Для sql server, если базы данных на одном сервере:

```
SELECT *
FROM db1.dbo.t1 A
  JOIN db2.dbo.t2 B ON A.col1=B.col1
```

где

```
db1, db2 - имена баз данных.
dbo - схема по умолчанию
t1 - имя таблиц
```

если базы данных на разных серверах, для кросс-серверных запросов можно использовать linked sever.

Comment: использование distinct не возможно?